# ashmem giving [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface, ashmem

In my rooted Android device,

```
jint fd = open("/dev/ashmem",O_RDWR);
```

gives -1 and fopen results in error 13. I've tried changing the permissions as well with chmod 777, but to no avail.

Any ideas? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps targeting Android 10 cannot directly use ashmem (/dev/ashmem) and must instead access shared memory via the NDK’s ASharedMemory class

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was due to the targetSdkVersion. It works when it's 28 but not at 30.